# no longer able to connect to network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, shutdown

New to Ubuntu, I installed rel. 12.04lts and I really enjoyed my experience.

I tried to connect to my wifi for the first time this morning and it didn't work. I tried the first thing: update my drivers through the settings menu. The process went through normally but my wifi was still not visible. 
I search in the forums and found that some people had success with WCID. I installed it and since then, not only that I still do not have access to wifi, I also lost my wired connection.
Uninstalling it hasn't changed the situation.

Another thing happened, that might or might not be related but since then, the shutting down of my pc doesn't work. The shut down routine starts but stays stuck on the ubuntu splash screen (the one with the 5 flashing dots) and I have to force the shut down.

Regards

Dell inspiron 1501

Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to correct the situation by first fully reinstalling Ubuntu and then following the instruction found in this page:

http://thoughts.stuart-edwards.info/index.php/sysadmin/linux/how-to-enable-wireless-in-ubuntu-12-10-on-a-dell-inspiron-1501